# Get React Bootstrap Form to Appear on Same Row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive, react-bootstrap

I have a bit of an issue with styling where the forms in `React-Bootstrap` don't align on the same row, because of the difference in Form Label string length. Here's my JSX:

```
return 
    (<Card style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>
      <Card.Body>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="goalSupremacy"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Goals Suprem</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="supremacyInput"
                name="supremacy"
                step="0.01"
                value={goalsSupremacy}
                min="-7.5"
                max="7.5"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setGoalsSupremacy(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="totalGoals"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Goals Total</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="totalGoalsInput"
                name="totalGoals"
                step="0.01"
                value={totalGoals}
                min="0"
                max="15"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setTotalGoals(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="cornerSupremacy"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Corner Suprem</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="cornerSupremacyInput"
                name="cornerSupremacy"
                step="0.25"
                value={cornersSupremacy}
                min="-7.5"
                max="7.5"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setCornersSupremacy(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="totalCorners"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Corners Total</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="totalCornersInput"
                name="totalCorners"
                step="0.25"
                value={totalCorners}
                min="0"
                max="15"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setTotalCorners(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="bookingsSupremacy"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Cards Suprem</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="bookingsSupremacyInput"
                name="bookingsSupremacy"
                step="0.01"
                value={bookingsSupremacy}
                min="-5"
                max="5"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setBookingsSupremacy(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="totalBookings"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Cards Total</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="totalBookingsInput"
                name="totalBookings"
                step="0.01"
                value={totalBookings}
                min="0"
                max="10"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setTotalBookings(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="homeRedPercentage"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Home Red %</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="homeRedInput"
                name="homeRed"
                step="0.01"
                value={homeExpectedRed}
                min="0"
                max="1"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setHomeExpectedRed(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="awayRedPercentage"></Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Away Red %</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                id="awayRedInput"
                name="awayRed"
                step="0.01"
                value={awayExpectedRed}
                min="0"
                max="1"
                style={{
                  width: "82.5px",
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setAwayExpectedRed(e.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col style={{ marginTop: "12.5px" }}>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                calculate();
              }}
            >
              Calculate
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>)
```

And an image of the issue. as you can see, the forms in `Home Red` and `Away Red` don't matchup. I'm not great at CSS or styling, so what needs to be done here in order to align the forms? Preferably a responsive solution, if possible...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the form 5 rows, 1st and 3rd containing the headings, 2nd and 4th containing the fields, 5th containing the button.

*I admit this is a pretty arbitrarily average solution, but it should do what you require, and I can't think how it wouldn't be responsive*